# Give an example of a continues function from an open and bounded interval $(a,b)\rightarrow I $ where $f(I)=ℝ$

Tags: functions, continuity

Give an example of a continues function from an open and bounded interval $(a,b)\rightarrow I  $ where  $f(I)=ℝ$

I'm having trouble coming up with a function that is has a bounded co-domain, yet an infinite domain for any values of a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\tan(x)$ restricted to the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Yes, however as far as I understand the exercise, it needs to be ANY interval e.g. (0,1)... Is there any continues function where this is possible?

Comment: Then shift and stretch the one given.

Comment: Also, I don't think it reads that way.  It reads as if the domain is fixed to be $(a,b)$ at the outset.  (Assuming that $(a,b) \to I$ means $(a,b)=I$.)

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! :)